# react-hook-form revalidating doesn't start

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, react-typescript

Found code example [at](https://react-hook-form.com/ts#UseFormReturn)

Forked a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-useformmethods-forked-586xh9?file=/src/App.tsx)(original is buggy and contains errors)

I want to use custom validation callbacks at each form input element, so I did provide options in `register`, but `validate` is triggered only at submition even `useForm` is configured with

```
{ reValidateMode: "onChange" }
```

The question is how to start `validate` on `onChange` event in that case described in sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but validate is triggered only at submition even useForm is configured with

Thats because `reValidateMode` is triggered only after form submission. To validate before the form is submitted, you should use `mode` property for `onChange`, `onBlur` etc events.

[Read more](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode)

Comment: Thank you dor answer, but the problem was in something else

Comment: I guess it must be outside of the snippet you shared @b442